# Jfree chart in Eclipse RCP application renders scaled up in OpenJDK 14

Tags: java, swt, eclipse-rcp, jfreechart

I have an Eclipse RCP application in which I have created one XY Line Chart using ChartFactory. The application was developed using Oracle JDK 8. Jfree chart was working fine in that. Now when I tried to port the application to OpenJDK 14, all the elements in the chart are scaled by the 1.25. Rest of the application did not cause any issue. I tried to find solution in Jfreechart forum, could not get any solution for the issue.

Basically complete chart is not getting displayed inside the SWT composite I created. However if I Restore Down the application, complete chart appears and same will be retained if I Maximize the application.

If anyone encountered same issue while porting the application, please let me know the fixes.

Thanks in advance

Comment: It may be related with different versions of native libraries used by SWT. Actually the jump from Java 8 to Java 14 is quite long. What Eclipse version do you have as a target? Do you have the same issue with Java 11? I would recommend to try Eclipse 2020-09 with Java 11 as a first migration step.

Comment: I'm using eclipse 2020-06. All Java versions starting from 9 to 14 are giving same issue. I have tried Java 11, same issue is found with that as well.

Answer (score 0):

This is because Swing (I assume you are using SWT_AWT) has a continous scale since Java 9.

See: https://news.kynosarges.org/2019/03/24/swing-high-dpi-properties/

You can synchronize Swing and SWT in a RCP with something like this
in the ApplicationWorkbenchWindowAdvisor class preWindowOpen() method at startup
for Windows and Linux (on MacOSX not needed).

```
int deviceZoom = DPIUtil.getDeviceZoom();
double zoom = deviceZoom / 100.0;
System.setProperty("sun.java2d.uiScale", Double.toString(zoom));
```

Of course you have to detect and edit this for high dpi screens accordingly.

Comment: Thanks. Will try this out